# Retrieve output parameter (identity column) from stored procedure with vb.net oledbcommand

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to retrieve an output parameter value (identity field) from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I looked at the following stackoverflow links. I am doing the same but still facing issues:
[Retrieving output parameter from stored procedure with oledb command vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714923/retrieving-output-parameter-from-stored-procedure-with-oledb-command-vb-net)
[Stored procedure - return identity as output parameter or scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142444/stored-procedure-return-identity-as-output-parameter-or-scalar)

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_Custom_InsertxRef]
       @DocumentID int,
       @RevNr int,
       @xRefDocument int,
       @xRefRevNr int,
       @xRefProjectId int,
       @RefCount int,
       @xRef int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @HasFullPath bit=1;
   DECLARE @RelativePath nvarchar(300)='';
   DECLARE @RefCountEdit float=NULL;
   DECLARE @RefTimeStamp as datetime=GETDATE();
   DECLARE @xrType as int = 1;

INSERT INTO [EpiGrid].[dbo].[XRefs]
           ([DocumentID]
           ,[RevNr]
           ,[XRefDocument]
           ,[XRefProjectID]
           ,[XRefRevNr]
           ,[HasFullPath]
           ,[RelativePath]
           ,[RefCount]
           ,[RefCountEdit]
           ,[RefTimeStamp]
           ,[XrType])
     VALUES
     (
        @DocumentID,
        @RevNr,
        @xRefDocument,
        @xRefProjectId,
        @xRefRevNr,
        @HasFullPath,
        @RelativePath,
        @RefCount,
        @RefCountEdit,
        @RefTimeStamp,
        @xrType
     )
   SET @xRef=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
   --select @xRef=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
   return @xRef;
END
```

My vb.net code:

```vb
Using connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(Connectionstring)
                connection.Open()
                Using command As New OleDbCommand("sp_Custom_InsertxRef", connection)
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    command.Parameters.Add("@DocumentID", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = epdmParDoc.ID
                    command.Parameters.Add("@RevNr", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = epdmParDoc.GetLocalVersionNo(parFolderId)
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRefDocument", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = targetReplaceDoc.ID
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRefRevNr", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = targetReplaceDoc.CurrentVersion
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRefProjectId", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = parFolderId
                    command.Parameters.Add("@RefCount", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = count
                    'command.Parameters.Add("@xRef", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.InputOutput).Value = -1
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRef", OleDbType.Integer)
                    command.Parameters("@xRef").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                    command.ExecuteReader()
                    xRefId = command.Parameters("@xRef").Value
                End Using
                connection.Close()
            End Using
```

I tried direction as output and return value and I see the same result. The record is created in the database (no errors) but my code gets nothing for the output parameter. Any idea why?

When I debug the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio it creates the record and I see the return or output (tried both) with correct value.

```
Exec [dbo].[sp_Custom_InsertxRef]
       @DocumentID =12,
       @RevNr =1,
       @xRefDocument = 15,
       @xRefRevNr =1,
       @xRefProjectId =1,
       @RefCount =2,
       @xRef=-1;
```

Please advise.

Comment: 1. Why use OleDB if Microsoft plans to scrap it? - use `SqlClient`. 2. Try to set size of your out parameter.

Comment: tried that too. I also tried setting it to 4. I tried both as separate line for the direction definition as well as part of the paramater add line. Same results. Using VS 2008 .net 3.5

Comment: I have not noticed but you do have "ExecuteReader"... use "ExecuteNonQuery" and you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you using execute reader function? if you don't want to return any value from stored then just use `ExecuteNonQuery()` method instead of `ExecuteReader()`. If you want to read value from stored procedure then you can use `ExecuteReader()` but, you must have assigned `DataReader` object.

For example

```
Dim dr As OleDBDataReader = Nothing
Try    
    dr  = command.ExecuteReader()
    IF dr.HasRows Then
        While (dr.Read())
            var value = dr.getValue(0)
        End While
    End IF
    dr.Close()
Catch
    'OleDB Exception will be thrown here 
Finally
    IF dr IsNot Nothing Then
        IF dr.IsClosed = false Then dr.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

but, to use above method you should make some changes in your stored procedure.

Replace following line:

```
SET @xRef=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
--select @xRef=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
return @xRef;
```

To

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

after these output parameter will not be needed in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same SP (no changes) with sqlclient instead of the oledb did the job. Probably a bug.

```
Using connection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionstrng)
                connection.Open()
                Using command As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_Custom_InsertxRef", connection)
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    command.Parameters.Add("@DocumentID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = epdmParDoc.ID
                    command.Parameters.Add("@RevNr", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = epdmParDoc.GetLocalVersionNo(parFolderId)
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRefDocument", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = targetReplaceDoc.ID
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRefRevNr", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = targetReplaceDoc.CurrentVersion
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRefProjectId", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = parFolderId
                    command.Parameters.Add("@RefCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = count
                    'command.Parameters.Add("@xRef", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.InputOutput).Value = -1
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xRef", SqlDbType.Int)
                    command.Parameters("@xRef").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                    command.ExecuteReader()
                    xRefId = command.Parameters("@xRef").Value
                End Using
                connection.Close()
            End Using
```

Comment: Still, use "ExecuteNonQuery"