# How do I run a stored procedure and use its results in MS Access VBA?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2016

I have a simple stored procedure that takes one parameter and has two output parameters. I want to call this stored procedure in Access VB and read the 2 output parameters to use them in the VB code. How do I do this?

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]
    @Input1 nvarchar(100),
    @Output1 int OUTPUT,
    @Output2 varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Output1 = 30
    SET @Output2 = 'OK'

    RETURN 0
END
```

This is the closest thing to what I'm looking for, but when I try to paste it into Access VBA it highlights a bunch of lines in red as if the syntax was way off.

```vb
Using connection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionstrng) 'Error here
    connection.Open() 'Error here
    Using command As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_Custom_InsertxRef", connection) 'Error here
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.Add("@DocumentID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = epdmParDoc.ID
        command.Parameters.Add("@RevNr", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = epdmParDoc.GetLocalVersionNo(parFolderId)
        command.Parameters.Add("@xRefDocument", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = targetReplaceDoc.ID
        command.Parameters.Add("@xRefRevNr", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = targetReplaceDoc.CurrentVersion
        command.Parameters.Add("@xRefProjectId", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = parFolderId
        command.Parameters.Add("@RefCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = count
        'command.Parameters.Add("@xRef", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.InputOutput).Value = -1
        command.Parameters.Add("@xRef", SqlDbType.Int) 'Error here
        command.Parameters("@xRef").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        command.ExecuteReader() 'Error here
        xRefId = command.Parameters("@xRef").Value
    End Using 'Error here
    connection.Close() 'Error here
End Using
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve output parameter (identity column) from stored procedure with vb.net oledbcommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462957/retrieve-output-parameter-identity-column-from-stored-procedure-with-vb-net-ol)

Comment: @Larnu only partially. I would like to read both output parameters, not just one.

Comment: Then add both output parameters to your code; the solution is no different.

Comment: @Larnu we're talking about Shell's answer in that link, right?

Comment: I would look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465923/2029983), which uses parameters.

Comment: @Larnu I tried that one but it seems as though the syntax is wrong for the version of Access that I'm using. The first 3 lines show up red for me and some more further in that code.

Comment: @Larnu Suggesting VB.Net answers for a question asking about VBA is not helpful. Those are using SqlClient or ADO.Net, neither are available in VBA.

Comment: The `Using` syntax does not exist in VBA. Solution for [DAO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao) and [ADODB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/command-object-parameters).

Answer (score 3):

You can use ADO to work with stored procedures, including output parameters.

You can be explicit about parameters, but ADO can also pull them from SQL server, which is nice.

```vb
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=localhost;Database=example;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
conn.Open 'Open connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command 'Declare a command object
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 'Connect it to SQL server
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 'It's a SP
cmd.CommandText = "spTest" 'And this is its name
cmd.Parameters.Refresh 'Get parameters from SQL server, you could manually declare them as well
cmd.Parameters("@Input1").Value = "High value!" 'Now parameters can be referenced by name
cmd.Execute 'Execute the stored procedure
Debug.Print cmd.Parameters("@output").Value 'And you can get the output values
```

Answer (score 1):

Erik's answer probably works as well, but I looked through some boilerplate code in the environment I'm working in and found this example, which works:

```
   Dim con As ADODB.connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command, prm As New ADODB.Parameter

   cmd.ActiveConnection = con
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   cmd.CommandText = "spStoredProcedureName"

   Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Input1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, strInput1)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm
   Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Output1", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 100)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm
   Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Output2", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 100)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm

   cmd.Execute
   
   Select Case cmd.Parameters("@Output2")
      Case "OK"
         'run some code...
      Case Else
         'run some other code...
   End Select
```

Comment: Yup, that's the "explicit" option I've referenced where you manually declare the types/sizes/etc. Works as well, just requires a bit more fiddling.